# sfgui is not building, looks like an issue with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, nmake

I'm trying to build sfgui using nmake through visual studios console but I'm getting this error:

> Scanning dependencies of target Canvas
>   [66%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/Canvas.dir/Canvas.cpp.obj
>   Canvas.cpp
>   **F:\Projects\Libs\SFGUI-0.2.3\examples\Canvas.cpp(115) : error C3861: 'gluPerspective': identifier not found**
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' : return code
>   '0x2'
>   Stop.
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
>   \VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop.
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
>   \VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop.

gluPerspective seems to be part of openGL and I'm not sure if it's supposed to exist but in my visual studio lib folder I cannot find opengl32.lib or glu32.lib but I do have the dll files in system32 for opengl

Comment: if you are building using nmake in visual studios i an fairly certain you dont need to actually set the additional library dependencies for anything OpenGL related since it is already there, the only thing you nee to do is set opengl32.lib and glu32.lib as additional dependencies through the linker process.

Comment: also you need to link GLEW ( glew.sourceforge.net ) as well, since on windows machines you only have OpenGL 1.0 installed by default and gluPerspective is part of OpenGL 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. To use SFML 2.3 I needed to get the latest SFGUI from git rather then the SFGUI site.